# forloop.counter0 in my django template is not working under original for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, templates

I have a for loop that goes through a list of inspections. I'd like to manipulate the things inside the  tag depending on different situations. For test, I tried to using jquery to print out the id of the element as it iterates, but the forloop seems to be stuck at 0. when I put inside the html it will iterate, but when I put inside the attribute 'id', it will not iterate. based on the code below, it should iterate as many times as there is i in inspections. but it wont. I also tried to get a console.log() fo the innerHTML of my  but all I get is the first item repeated over and over instead of going down the list (on the webage however it looks lile it iterated ok, just not on the backend I guess?).
note that jquery was imported at the beginning of the html. this is just snippet of issue.

I'd appreciate any help.

my code:

```
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-inspection" role="tabpanel"
                                 aria-labelledby="nav-inspection-tab">
                                <div class="container"></br></br>
                                    {% for i in inspections %}
                                        <div class="card - mb-3" style="width: 40 rem;">
                                            <div class="card-body">
                                                <h3 class="card-title">{{i.Title}} - <span title="" id="s{{forloop.counter0}}">{{i.Condition}}</span>
                                                </h3>
                                                <script type="text/javascript">
                                                    console.log(document.querySelector('[title]').innerHTML);
                                                    $(document).ready(function(){
                                                        alert($('[title]').attr("id"));
                                                    });
                                                </script>
                                                <p>{{i.Desc}}</p>
                                                <h4><span class="badge badge-primary">{{i.Cost}}</span></h4>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Comment: i wil assume that `inspections is from a django model` then why not use `s{{ i.pk }}` instead of `s{{forloop.counter0}}` and try to put the `<script> tag ` outside the forloop it is a better design

Comment: That's actually neat idea. They already have a pk for each row, so yeah that would make sense. Thanks a lot, @ThiernoAmadouSow !

Answer (score 1):

I actually fixed it myself. I just used the `$('[title]').each(function(){});` to iterate over each span created and toggle the class. pretty easy find.

```
{% for i in inspections.all %}
    <div class="card - mb-3" style="width: 40 rem;">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h3 class="card-title">{{i.Title}} - <span title="inspection" id="s{{forloop.counter0}}" class="">{{i.Condition}}</span>
            </h3>
            <p>{{i.Desc}}</p>
            <h4><span class="badge badge-primary">{{i.Cost}}</span></h4>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("[title='inspection']").each(function(){
            if ($(this).html() == 'Poor'){
                $(this).toggleClass("badge badge-danger");
            } else if ($(this).html() == 'Not Satisfactory') {
                $(this).toggleClass("badge badge-warning");
            } else if ($(this).html() == 'Satisfactory'){
                $(this).toggleClass("badge badge-success");
            }else if ($(this).html() == 'Not Inspected'){
                $(this).toggleClass("badge badge-secondary");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Maintain indentation in the code properly.